# change from PDO to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I change the below to mysql? This is my authentication page.

I have tried changing but all it gives me is a blank page with no error. All my other pages are in mysql format and I don't want to use PDO.

```
require 'connect.php';

session_start();

$username = "";
$password = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];

}

echo $username ." : ".$password;

$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


if($query->rowCount() == 0){
    header('Location: ind.php?err=1');
}else{

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['role'];

    echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    session_write_close();

    if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "admin"){
        header('Location: adminhome.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: userhome.php');
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't change from mysql_* because it's deprecated. lol

Comment: use `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` to check error in page !!

Comment: Just keep using PDO please.

Comment: I think you don't must change PDO  to mysql , but you must to change mysql to PDO on all your code ^^

Comment: you are right #aldrin though i had created all my other pages using mysql :) ,that will require me change all of them to PDO.

Comment: okay guys i then should stick to PDO.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial @flevian: [Roll your own PDO class](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/). Although it's a bit old, it's still perfectly fine. You'll find it an easy to understand tutorial and it will make updating your code a lot easier :)

Comment: thanks @icecub on it

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a grave misunderstanding here.

As [several](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4877278/aldrin27) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999617/vincent-decaux) have pointed out in comments, you [don't want to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) your code to use `mysql_` -style functions. These functions have been [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) since PHP 5.5.0. Setting this aside, it also needs to be used very carefully to [avoid SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

I understand that for some reason you may not want to use PDO, in which case you do have options like [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Please also see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.abstract.php) for other database abstraction layers.

My suggestion is that you:

1. Debug what's wrong with your login page.
2. Refactor your other pages to use something else than `mysql_` functions.
3. Evaluate whether existing CMS or PHP frameworks would be more fit for your use case.